# running tests via the terminal and rake, load test_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a problem running my tests from the terminal and from rake, e.g. rake test:integration

At the moment, I have the requires for test_helper.rb specified like this:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
```

This works fine when running them from the terminal but obviously when it is ran from rake, the directory is different and the process cannot find the test_helper file.

I think I want to add to this to my $load_path but I am not sure how to add it when running only in the test environment.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can revert to just `require 'test_helper'` (the default for integration tests, at least with Rails 2.3.x). This will allow tests to run from a rake task, and as long as you `cd` to the `test` directory within your rails app, you can run tests via the terminal with `ruby integration/your_test.rb`.

Comment: I am on rails 3 and this does not work from the test directory.  I think it has been removed from the load_path in rails 3.

Comment: If I have require 'test_helper' and use the I switch it works, ruby -I test test/integration/my_test.rb.  Still not happy with this approach